# Aggregate data stored as time_t in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents stored in MongoDB which include a `created` field as a unix style `time_t`:

e.g.

```
{"created": 1137459055216, "qty": 3 }
```

How can I aggregate this data by month through a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert unix epoch ms counts to native `Date` objects for aggregation by adding the count to `new Date(0)`. For example:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: {$month: {$add: [new Date(0), '$created']}},
        qty: {$sum: '$qty'}
    }}
])
```

Or if you want aggregate by month and year, add a `$project` that does the conversion and then you can easily reference it multiple times in your `$group`:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        createdDate: {$add: [new Date(0), '$created']},
        qty: '$qty'
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            year: {$year: '$createdDate'}, 
            month: {$month: '$createdDate'}
        },
        qty: {$sum: '$qty'}
    }}
])
```

Note that if `created` is a *seconds* count instead of a ms count, you also need to multiply it by 1000:

```js
createdDate: {$add: [new Date(0), { $multiply: ['$created', 1000] }]}
```

Comment: Worked great -- for completeness since the stored times are in seconds you need to mulitple by 1000 before adding:  createdDate: {$add: [new Date(0), { $multiply: [ '$created', 1000] }]},

Comment: Great.  The `created` time from your example doc only made sense if it was ms so that's what I was assuming. I'll add that to the answer, thanks.